# C++ overloading += operator with double pointers

Tags: c++, pointers, operator-overloading

So I'm trying to overload the += operator for a dictionary program assignment.
This is my function:

```
Definition& Definition::operator += (const String& input) {
    String** temp;
    temp = new String*[numDefs + 1];
    temp[0] = new String[numDefs];
    for (int i = 0; i < numDefs; i++)   {
            temp[i] = def[i];
    }
    temp[0][numDefs] = input;
    delete[] def;
    def = temp;
    numDefs++;
    return *this;
}
```

However when I try to put 'input' into 'temp' it doesn't seem to work. This is my String class function for allocating string to string:

```
String& String::operator=(const String& input) {
    data = NULL;
    (*this) = input.getData();
    return *this;
}
```

and:

```
String& String::operator=(const char* input) {
    if (data != input)
    {
        if (data != NULL)
        {
            delete[] data;
            data = NULL;
        }
        data_len = strSize(input);
        if (input != NULL)
        {
            data = new char[data_len + 1];
            strCopy(data, input);
        }
    }
    return *this;
}
```

Can't seem to find the problem.

Comment: *However when I try to put 'input' into 'temp' it doesn't seem to work.* Please define clearly what doesn't seem to work means. Crash? Doesn't compile? Wrong result?

Comment: I think it will be difficult to answer this question without seeing your class definition.

Comment: the error don't seem to lie in the code you given. Is there a particular reason you avoid std::string and std::vector?

Comment: What is `def`??? When you assign a pointer to a pointer like so: `temp[i] = def[i];` you're not making a deep copy, so `delete[] def;` deletes the memory pointed to by *both* `temp` and `def`. You need to allocate memory for each string pointer in `temp`, and then perform a deep copy.

Answer (score 1):

There was an answer posted a minute ago that the user deleted and helped me, I changed the code to:

```
Definition& Definition::operator += (const String& input) {
    String** temp;
    int tempSize = numDefs + 1;
    temp = new String*[tempSize];
    for (int i = 0; i < numDefs; i++)   {
        temp[i] = new String;
        temp[i] = def[i];
    }
    temp[numDefs] = new String;
    (*temp[numDefs]) = input;
    delete[] def;
    def = temp;
    numDefs = tempSize;
    return *this;
}
```

Whoever it was, Thanks!